# Send Email with php with html form data

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have no idea how php works. Im using JavaScript for every logic but its only for client use and php is for server i think. Im getting a 405 (Method Not Allowed) error.

How can i send a email (Example: "example@gmail.com") to myself with the input data from a html form?

```js
//** IF u need it **

// Working Contact Form
$('#contact-form').submit(function() {
  var action = $(this).attr('action');

  $("#message").slideUp(750, function() {
    $('#message').hide();

    $('#submit').before('').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    $.post(action, {
        name: $('#name').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
        comments: $('#comments').val(),
      },
      function(data) {
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
        $('#message').slideDown('slow');
        $('#cform img.contact-loader').fadeOut('slow', function() {
          $(this).remove()
        });
        $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
        if (data.match('success') != null) $('#cform').slideUp('slow');
      }
    );

  });

  return false;

});

// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function() {
  'use strict'
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation')

    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        console.log("test")
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault()
          event.stopPropagation()
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated')
      }, false)
    })
  }, false)
}())
```

```css
//Ignore CSS, doesnt matter
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="php/contact.php" name="contact-form" id="contact-form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="form-control border rounded" placeholder="Name :">
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--end col-->
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input name="email" id="email" type="email" class="form-control border rounded" placeholder="Email :">
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--end col-->
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input name="subject" id="subject" class="form-control border rounded" placeholder="Betreff :">
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--end col-->
      </div>
      <!--end row-->
    </div>
    <!--end col-->

    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="4" class="form-control border rounded" placeholder="Nachricht :"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--end col-->
  </div>
  <!--end row-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-right">
      <input type="submit" id="submit" name="send" class="submitBnt btn btn-pill btn-custom" value="Senden">
      <div id="simple-msg"></div>
    </div>
    <!--end col-->
  </div>
  <!--end row-->
</form>
<!--end form-->
```

Im using VS-Code with LiveServer extension to create a website. Can i use php there or what is the problem? Btw, still have a problem with JS i think..?!

If anybody know how to help, please comment! Thank you.

Comment: @MarkOverton No it doesnt. Ive already seen this post. My problem is, that im getting a 405 (Method Not Allowed) error and i dont know how to solve this.

Comment: Then the address to which you send the `$.post` request on does not allow the `POST` method. Instead try the `GET` method, or allow `POST`. But it is hard to see what is happening if we can't take a look at your PHP.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Thank you for the hint. THe problem is, ive never used php before. I dont know how to use this but on some other stackoverflow.com sites they say, i can use this: 
`<?php
$to      = 'test@gmail.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?> ` and thats why i added the js so you may can tell me how to write it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `.php` file opens with the `<?php` keyword. It indicates that this file contains PHP code. HTML can be used in PHP files so there is no different file type for that. Close the php file with `?>`.

You could also have single lines of PHP code in for example your HTML.

```
<?php $title = 'Hello World'; ?>
```

```
<h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
```

You'll need to collect the data that send to the server. PHP has *global variables* which are variables that are available everywhere in any file. For example the `$_GET` variable. If you use the `GET` method to send your data, then you will be able to *read* that data from the global `$_GET` variable in the file that you send it to.

`$_GET` is an [associative array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). So sent data is stored like so:

```
[
  'name' => '',
  'email' => '',
  'comments' => ''
]
```

Associative arrays are comparable to objects in JavaScript. They both have a key and a value. Check if a key is set with the [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function in PHP.

Because you are allowing the user to send data it is important to *sanitize* their data. It can contain malicious code and should be treated as such until you have *sanitized* it. [`filter_var`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) is a PHP function which can do that for you.

Now that you have your data and cleaned it you can use the `mail` function to send a mail to the an email address. The `mail` function returns a boolean based on if the mail was sent successfully.

Good luck!

```
<?php

/** 
 * Get all the send data from JS.
 * $_GET is a global PHP variable. It is an array
 * which contains the data sent with the GET method.
 */
$name     = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : '';
$email    = isset($_GET['email']) ? $_GET['email'] : '';
$comments = isset($_GET['comments']) ? $_GET['comments'] : '';

/**
 * All data that a user can send must be treated as dirty.
 * Therefor it is important to filter all malicious characters
 * from the data. Otherwise you are open to vulnerabilities.
 */
$name     = filter_var($name, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email    = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$comments = filter_var($comments, FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);

/**
 * Now the data is received and sanitized we can use it
 * to send an email with.
 */
$to      = $email; // The email address to send to.
$from    = 'sender@example.com'; // Your email address.
$subject = 'the subject'; 
$message = $comments; // I assume comments is the message. 
$headers = 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $from . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); 

/**
 * Send the email.
 * The mail() function returns a true or false based
 * on if the email was sent successfully.
 */
$mail_status = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

/**
 * Send a message back to JS based on if the mail has beent sent or not.
 */
if ($mail_status === true) {
  return 'Mail has been sent';
} else {
  return 'Sending the mail has failed';
}

?>
```

Comment: One thing to add. I still got the 405 (Method Not Allowed) error in the console output. Is this a error because im using VS Code Live Server or how do i have to handle this one?

Comment: No, it is because you use `$.post` which, like the name suggests, uses the `POST` method to send your data from JS to PHP. Use the equivalent jQuery function for `GET` instead. It might even be called `$.get` ;)

Comment: I changed the `$.post` to `$.get` but it still dont work. I dont receive any email from anything. The error message isnt there anymore, so this is good i think, now i got a other notification in vs-code: `live reload is not possible without body or head tag`.

Comment: Well, you gotta run PHP on a server of some kind. Can be local or hosted. Do research on how to setup your PHP server. Live-reload won't suffice.